# Retrieving php variables from ajax call but not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

when I use this code nothing and call the ajax nothing happens and I was looking at some online forums saying I need to use json encode to pass variables over ajax but it just echos it at the top of the webpage.

AjaxTesting

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            event.preventDefault(),
            url:'ajaxUser.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.id);
            }
        )};
    });
    </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input name="userName">
      <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" id="test">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajaxUser

```
    <?php
    echo json_encode(array('id' => 123, 'messageid' => "test"));
    ?>
```

Comment: you can get the those data in the ajaxTesting.php like `$_POST['time']` etc

Comment: @guradio sorry I didnt come off right I mean like I want ajax to alert() something from php this is just a small example that I dumbed down

Comment: what do you get in alert?

Comment: nothing it doesn't work at all

Comment: where is `post()` called?i dont see it. you can bind an event handler on button click then send the ajax.

Comment: change type of `button` from `submit to button` or add `e.preventDefault()` because it refreshes the page. also id is `#` , `.` is for class. change `$('.test')` to `$('#test')`

Comment: Now the question code doesn't look anything like what it did before rendering my answer virtually useless in comparison

Comment: im changing it up based on what im being told

Comment: @JacobWebb what are you getting in alert now?

Comment: @guradio no I am not getting anything is there a chatroom we could discuss this in?

Comment: `event.preventDefault(),` what is this?remove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `event` parameter called in click function. Don't call `preventDefault()` within ajax function ,also you need to code your js within `document.ready()` if you want to write in header element !!

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>       
    </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input name="userName">
      <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" id="test">
    </form>
    <script>
    $("#test").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajaxUser.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.id);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Should work

Comment: Now that I can retrieve data thanks to you and some others is there a way to send data such as userName ?

Answer (score 0):

The php code needs to be in a different file named `AjaxTesting.php` and you never call the function `post()` in the javascript. So we can call it inside a form submit event handler

Try adding:

```
$(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault()
       post();
   })
});
```

Also note that the html page needs to be running on the same server and not from local file for ajax to work

Comment: Updating my question to what I now have but still not displaying anything.

Comment: Look in browser console dev tools network tab to see if request is made and what it;s status is

Comment: it navigated to the ajaxTesting.php and shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: what's the rest of the message? Those error messages are meaningful and important and will also tell you where in the code the problem is

Comment: note that the echo needs a space after php opening tag. Inspecting the request in dev tools network probably shows a 500 server error status

Comment: it has one but the way its posting in this forum removed it for some reason

Comment: not right for others to modify completely  changed question code that doesn't resemble anything like original and get accepted answer. That code wouldn't have even come to being without the help I gave you